# Continuous invertible map on [0,1) must be increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous, invertible map on $[0,1)$. How do we prove that $f$ must be increasing, and thus $f(0)=0$ and $\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)=1$? It's simple to see that $f$ must be either strictly increasing or decreasing. I understand how this must work, having difficulty with formality.

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ and $x\neq 0$, what happens on $[0,x)$ and $(x,1)$?

Comment: Well there must be a pretty image of 0.  If f (x) = 0 and 0 <x then for y <x <z we have f (y) > f (x) and f (z) > f (x) which by intermediate value theorem will show f is not invertable.